# How to mock one element in an Array in javascript test -- Solved

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm writing a javascript test, and am trying to mock one element in an array, I'm not sure this is the correct way to say it, but this is what I'm trying to do.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr[0].mockReturnValue(4); 
//so in the end, I want the array to be [4,2,3] when I pass it into another function.
```

Is there anyway I can do this?

Solved--
arr[0] = 4;

Comment: Do you have more code to show context? That will definitely impact the solutions you're given.

Comment: Hey @JoelHager, what kind of context are you looking for? Upon reading the jest doc, I was not able to find a method to mock the element within a const array. Do you know any method would do so?

Comment: why would you want to mock it? why not actually changing it? you can make a copy of it and change the value.

Comment: @Amir yep I just realized const array can still be changed. New to javascript lol.